# WinSCP script file with username and password

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

How to run WinSCP script file that needs username and password.

I want to run this using batch file:

```
cd C:\Program Files\WinSCP

WinSCP.com

open ftp://ipaddress:port -passive=on
```

....after that, I need to input my username

...and after that I need to input my password

Here is my batch file, but it always fails:

```
cd C:\Program Files\WinSCP
WinSCP.com /command "option batch on" "option confirm off" "open ftp://ipaddress:port -passive=on"""
"-username myusername"
"-password mypassword"
"cd PO"
"cd D:\"
"mget *.*"
```

Thank for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
open ftp://user:password@ipaddress:port
```

References:

- [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open);
- [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url)

---

Also note that WinSCP has the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) for recursive uploads. The `mput` is just an alias to the `put`, supported for compatibility reasons.

---

You probably wanted to do `lcd D:\`, instead of `cd D:\`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the help file you are making up your own parameters which is why they don't work.

Use traditional means of specifing your password as Help shows. NOTE: These techniques are REMOVED from Windows for security reasons.

```
ftp://username:password@ftp.microsoft.com
```

According to Help you can also pipe standard in with parameters.

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline